# Set point geometry of a list of points in PYQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geometry

I want to create a temporary point layer from a list of points.
The point list is:

arr_error = [[547162.6286000004, 187063.95659999922]]

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer('Point', 'Error_point', 'memory')
    pr = vl.dataProvider()
    pr.addAttributes([QgsField("Name", QVariant.String)])
    vl.updateFields()
    for x in arr_error:
        
        fet = QgsFeature()
        pt = QgsPointXY(x[0],x[1])
        
        fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(pt))
        fet.setAttributes(['Error'])
        pr.addFeatures([fet])
    vl.updateExtents()
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([vl])
```

This creates a layer, feature is added to layer. But geometry is not being set. What mistake i am doing in the code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a Coordinate Reference System for your layer.
You can do this when you define your `QgsVectorLayer` object like this:

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=EPSG:3857', 'Error_point', 'memory')
```

Or subsequently like this:

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer('Point', 'Error_point', 'memory')
vl.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857'))
```

Note: I just used EPSG:3857 for this example, to show the syntax. Of course, you should use whatever CRS your point coordinates are actually in.

Comment: Yes, I had not provided the CRS information. I added CRS, and it worked fine. Thanks :)

crs = QgsProject.instance().crs().authid()

vl = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=' + crs, 'Error_point', 'memory')